# python pygame using spyder

Tags: python, pygame, spyder

When I code this pygame import, it doesn't work  with spyder:

```
import pygame

Window_width=700
Window_hight=500

pygame.init()
size= (Window_width, Window_hight)
screen= pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

pygame.quit()
```

The answer of spyder is :

```
>Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 13:40:45) [MSC v.1500 
64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

 >File "C:/Users/hpinko/Desktop/python scripts/game.py", line 1, in <module>
   import pygame

ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Please, help me to fix this.

Comment: Have you installed pygame?

Comment: yes i did unstalled

Answer (score 1):

It might be because pygame module is not installed on your pc. You can install it by using pip.

**Step 1**: Go to the directory in which python is installed on command prompt by using `cd c:\Python27\`.
**Step 2**: Go to scripts folder by entering the command `cd Scripts`. You might want to add this folder to your path variable to avoid navigating to  `c:\python27\Scripts` folder every time you want to install a package
**Step 3**: Install pygame by running `pip install pygame`

Comment: are you getting any error? If yes then what is the error message?

Comment: ImportError: No module named pygame
 maybe u didn't install it correctly....do you know how to installed it with spyder?

Comment: Can you share the output of all the commands I mentioned above(especially last one error) ? I don't  use spyder but a package installed with pip should work with spyder(unless spyder is using another version of python installed on your machine)

Comment: Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 13:40:45) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
  File "C:/Users/hpinko/Desktop/python scripts/game.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame

ImportError: No module named pygame

Comment: You have anaconda installed. Can you try "conda install -c cogsci pygame" on your command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I followed Tom's advice and used CMD to navigate to the Scripts folder.  Then I went to https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted and used py -m pip install -U pygame --user for windows installation.

Comment: yes, before i could only access pygame using IDLE.  now i can access using spyder 4.0